# How to combine two DS.RecordArray in an Ember.ArrayController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to create a view in Ember that combines records from two models and sorts them according to a common attribute.

I have made a working fiddle, but I am not sure if I am doing it right.

http://jsfiddle.net/UtrtJ/15/

Is there a better way to do this?

[Edit] slightly updated the example to http://jsfiddle.net/UtrtJ/16/ which I think is better

Comment: What are your issues with the way you have implemented this ? To me it looks just fine. On the other hand, I would be more interested in looking into just why you need to combine data from different sources into a single controller. I don't know your domain, but at first glance that's something I would generally try to separate out somehow.

Comment: The reason I am combining the data is because they are supposed to be displayed together, sorted by a common attribute. There is not a single resource that contains all the data I need, so I need to "mix" them.

Comment: Then I don't see anything in particular that is wrong with your code. Of course, in a production app you wouldn't use Fixtures, and so you could bind your "bar" and "foo" properties to an Ember Data Query. That way your content array would be kept updated with changes to the underlying data. Other than that, it looks fine to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two Record Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590906/merge-two-record-arrays)