# Merge two Record Arrays

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two different models in my application

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  title:   DS.attr('string')
});

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  title:   DS.attr('string')
});
```

Both foo and bar models get their data from different models in my backend.
They both have some common fields, like title. But others are also different (and I will need different views for them).

However, when displaying a list of them, I would like to be able to merge them and order them as if they were the same object.

Unfortunately from what I see in the ember-data codebase, that doesn't seem to be possible.
Any idea on solutions ?

Comment: Basically, that would be something like STI in ember-data.

Comment: So you are basically looking for something like `App.Store.findAll(DS.Model)`?

Comment: Yes, something like that (and which would allow me to have a middle model to retrieve only the two models I want). But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've opened an issue on GitHub https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/338

Comment: The corresponding Pull Request to the previously openend issue is here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved in the latest versions of Ember Data with the implementation of [findAll](https://github.com/pangratz/data/commit/ebf508e1e54eeb1e075488ba09cf9e8ffeb612af).

Therefore, we can do :

```
DS.store.findAll(DS.Model)
```

Which will load all records from all models.